# How to use a join table when query also contains geography data, in a multi-id query?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

**Places Table**

- PlaceId PK
- Name
- GeoPoint (GeoPoint type)
- etc...

**PlaceCats Table (the join table)**

- PlaceId PK FK
- CatId PK FK

**PlaceCategories Table**

- CatId PK
- Name
- etc...

Here's my query, to return places, with entries in the PlaceCats table (by a series of catIds), and within 25km of a Lat/Lng value.

```
SELECT Places.* 
FROM Places 
     INNER JOIN PlaceCats 
             ON Places.PlaceId = PlaceCats.PlaceId 
WHERE PlaceCats.CatId IN (2,3,4,5) 
AND Places.GeoPoint.STDistance(geography::Point(35.75094975999387, 139.39780220389366, 4326)) < ((25 * 1000)) 
ORDER BY Places.Name ASC
```

It's returning places, but I need to add DISTINCT after the SELECT... apparently you can't use DISTINCT when selecting geography data. I need to make sure I'm not getting the same place multiple times (as they can have multiple entries in the join table).

**Update**

When I insert a place into the Places table, the GeoPoint is set like so:

```
SqlGeography.Point(sentPlace.Lat.Value, sentPlace.Lng.Value, 4326);
```

Comment: Thanks for the formatting edit cularis, much easier to read the query now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It look to me like you have your long/lats the wrong way round.

As for selecting DISTINCT geographies, you can perform the DISTINCT operation over the WKT (Well Known Text) in a nested query, see below:

```
SELECT 
GEOGRAPHY::STGeomFromText(WKT, [PROJECTION]) AS GEOG
FROM
(
    SELECT DISTINCT
    GEOG.STAsText() AS WKT
    FROM 
    [TABLE_NAME]
) a
```

Your query would look something like this:

```
SELECT 
    a.* 
,   GEOGRAPHY::STGeomFromText(WKT, 4326) AS GEOG
FROM 
(
    SELECT DISTINCT
        Places.[COL1]
    ,   Places.[COL2]
    ,   Places.[COL3]
    ,   Places.[COL4]
    ...
    ...
    ,   Places.GeoPoint.STAsText() AS WKT
    FROM 
    Places 
    INNER JOIN 
    PlaceCats 
    ON 
    Places.PlaceId = PlaceCats.PlaceId 
    WHERE PlaceCats.CatId IN (2,3,4,5) 
    AND 
    Places.GeoPoint.STDistance(GEOGRAPHY::Point(35.75094975999387, 139.39780220389366, 4326)) < ((25 * 1000)) 
    ORDER BY Places.Name ASC 
)a
```

One further tip, assuming you have a spatial index on your table, it speeds spatial queries up no end by using an index hit:

```
SELECT *
FROM 
[TABLE_NAME] WITH(INDEX([INDEX_NAME]))
WHERE
GEOG.STIntersects.(GEOGRAPHY::Point([Longitude], [Latitude], 4326)) = 1
```

Comment: I've been using geography::Point([Latitude], [Longitude], 4326) in my queries fine... until I started trying to modify the join to use IN (WHERE PlaceCats.CatId IN (2,3,4,5)).

I updated my description... the query is returning places, but I need to get DISTINCT places. I don't quite follow your nested query, how would that fit into the query I presented?

In the index, what values should I provide the long/lat? Would this be common points where I query from?

Comment: I have edited my answer to include what i think your query shouold look like, hope it works! As for the index, there is a specific "Spatial Index" you can use in SQL 2008.  Also, didnt know that the Geographies worked with Lat/Longs rather than Long/Lats!  Learn something new everyday huh!

Comment: Thanks for the query. What is the WKT value? I understand it stands for Well Known Text... Also, in the nested query, Places.GEOG.STASText() AS WKT throws an error: "Invalid column name 'GEOG'." I edited my question to show how I'm inserting GeoPoint data into the table, maybe it matters?

Comment: Ahh, sorry yes, GEOG should be "GeoPoint". The WKT will just be the geography represented as Text e.g.: POINT (169.724 -46.2413).

Comment: Thanks, yet again. ;) I updated it from GEOG to GeoPoint... new error: "Could not find method 'STASText' for type 'Microsoft.SqlServer.Types.SqlGeography' in assembly 'Microsoft.SqlServer.Types'"

Sorry for being such a hassle. ;[

Comment: Again, my fault, its very sensative with the case, it should read STAsText().

Comment: Doh, I found it on MSDN right as you commented. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb933970.aspx

Working great, thanks a ton!